# How to make goal completion work on hashchange?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have an `AngularJS` webapp where there are no separate pages.
I have set up a goal completion so that there's a code that is triggered by a javascript event,
and it has the following structure:

```
function call_completion(){

window.google_conversion_id = 973404965;
window.google_conversion_language = "en";
window.google_conversion_format = "1";
window.google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
window.google_conversion_label = "doGHCLPK2wkQpfaT0AM";
window.google_conversion_value = 1.000000;
window.google_remarketing_only = false;

var s = document.createElement('script');
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.src = '//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js';
document.body.appendChild(s);

}
```

Yet, I can't see any completions registered in Google Analytics. What could be the problem?
Is this the correct way to do it? Is there perhaps some nifty plugin that gets this problem right?

**UPDATE:**

For the new Universal Analytics, there is a plugin called [angular-ga](https://github.com/panrafal/angular-ga).
It eliminates the whole question.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't append the script to your view, since it won't be executed.
You should use this:

```
$.getScript( "http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js" );
```

To get the script working on that page and execute it.
Hope this helps :)

Comment: I don't think you're right, I did a test case and it ran the script on all browsers, after inclusion.

Comment: yes, I did. If you look at the code of $.getScript, you can see that it does not "run" the script. It is because it is run automatically once you add it to the page. It is just a handy shorthand. Please see my solution in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `<noscript>` part also has to be included.

Something like this:

```
$('body')
  .append('\
    <!-- Google Code for Subscriptions Conversion Page -->\n\
    <script type="text/javascript">\n\
    /* <![CDATA[ */\n\
    var google_conversion_id = 973404965;\n\
    var google_conversion_language = "en";\n\
    var google_conversion_format = "1";\n\
    var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";\n\
    var google_conversion_label = "doGHCLPK2wkQpfaT0AM";\n\
    var google_conversion_value = 1.000000;\n\
    var google_remarketing_only = false;\n\
    /* ]]> */\n\
    </script>\
  ');

$('body')
  .append('<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">')
  .append($('<noscript>')
    .append($('<div style="display:inline;">')
      .append('<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/973404965/?value=1.000000&amp;label=doGHCLPK2wkQpfaT0AM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>')
    )
  );
```